# surprising behavior of MySql not operator

Tags: mysql, casting, operator-precedence, not-operator

I expected this query to return all columns as 0, how is the right expression 1?

```
select (not(55))=1, !(55)=1, not(55)=1 ;

+-------------+---------+-----------+
| (not(55))=1 | !(55)=1 | not(55)=1 |
+-------------+---------+-----------+
|           0 |       0 |         1 |
+-------------+---------+-----------+
```

I find this surprising that NOT and ! aren't equivalent, and that the parens are significant.

[edit: simplified the query from original post]

Comment: It appears SQLite has a similar interpretation for `select (not(55))=1, not(55)=1 ;` [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c03c8/1)

Comment: @Uueerdo, I believe the precedence difference from NOT and ! is the correct explanation. It almost seems as if there is some optimization happening that makes sense for booleans, but NOT for ints. E.g. `!x=1` <=> `x=0` <=> `!(x=1)`

Comment: I think the operator precedence(from highest to lowest) : (`! -> = -> NOT`) concludes it.

Comment: @GregGirty I wouldn't call it optimization; I would just call it the implementation of the typically expected behavior of boolean operators on ints (established by early programming languages).

Answer (score 1):

in your first column the code is like  (mysql perform an implicit evaluation of the code  (55)=0 )

```
select  (55)=1 from dual;  /* result 0  false*/
```

then

```
select  not (55)=1 from dual; /* resul  1 true alias not false */
```

Answer (score 0):

Greg:

According to MYSQL documentation of **IFNULL(expr1,expr2)**:

> If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns
>   expr2.  IFNULL() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the
>   context in which it is used.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: This doesn't fully explain the problem.

Comment: It does: IFNULL(55,0) is 0, then NOT(0) is 1, and then 1=1 is True, that's the reason the column result is 1...

Comment: Are you sure that `IFNULL(55, 0)` is `0`, because AFAIK the number `55` is not `NULL`.

Comment: Tim, you are right, thanks for the correction. The parenthesis have priorities. Boolean operators like "NOT" does respect parenthesis presence...

Comment: You were correct, the IFNULL was not relevant to the effect. I've updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: it's different to have "select (not(55))=1" vs "select not(55)=1". Sometimes parenthesis can change the whole scenario...

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me what you are seeing is that the comparison `=` operator has higher precedence than the `NOT` operator:

`NOT( IFNULL(55,0)) = 1` is equivalent to `NOT (IFNULL(55,0)=1)`

`(NOT( IFNULL(55,0))) = 1` is equivalent to `(NOT IFNULL(55,0)) = 1`

`!(IFNULL(55,0)) = 1` is equivalent to exactly what is looks like; and indicates `!` has higher or equal precedence to `=`.

*Which is corroborated by the official docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operator-precedence.html).*

I would guess the different precedence of `!` and `NOT` has something to do with the slightly different semantics and expected uses of the two operators. I've never tried, but I am pretty sure `x IS !NULL` and `x ! IN ([set])` are not permitted.